# python - Unresolved reference and I don' know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, playing-cards

I'm trying to make a small program that tells you what your chances of getting a particular card are and asks for what cards were drawn.
When it gets to asking for what card was drawn it says Unresolved reference in the code and Im not sure what it means or why it says that

```
cards = 52

ace = 4
queen = 4
king = 4
jack = 4

two = 4
three = 4
four = 4
five = 4
six = 4
seven = 4
eight = 4
nine = 4
ten = 4  

def ask_what_card_was_drawn():
    drawncard = input("What card did you draw?: ")
    if drawncard == ace:
        ask_what_card_was_drawn()
    elif drawncard == queen:
        queen == queen - 1
        cards == cards - 1
    elif drawncard == jack:

    #code kinda repeats itself here#

    #tried experimenting with -= 1 instead#
    elif drawncard == nine:
        nine == -1
        cards == cards - 1
    elif drawncard == "ten":
        ten -= 1
        cards -= 1
    else:
        print("Error")
    print("Cards left are: ")
    print("Cards = ", cards)
    print("     ace = ", ace)
    #kinda repeated itself again here aswell#
    print("     ten = ", ten)

    ask_what_card_was_drawn()
```

Comment: can you copy the exact error?

Comment: And you don't even reproduce the complete code.

Comment: I went to paste the whole code but stackoverflow said my post is mostly code so I removed a few lines so I could post

Comment: Thank you Jordan, if it helps I'll try get a full screen shot of the updated code and errors

Comment: I just have to say if I ever saw someone in a job interview write code with the line "six = 4", I would look no further...

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code. The first one being that you reference global variables before you shadow them into your local scope resulting into an `UnboundLocalError`. You need to tell Python that you are working with globals, e.g:

```
def ask_what_card_was_drawn():
    global cards, ace, queen, king, jack, two, three, four, five, size, seven, eight, nine, ten
    drawncard = input("What card did you draw?: ")
    ...
```

The second issue is that you are using `==` to assign a value instead of `=`. The first one is a condition that check for equality, while the second assign a value to a name. So for example, the following line:

```
queen == queen - 1
```

Is effectively interpreted as `False`, because `queen` do not equals `queen - 1`. You need to only use one `=` like so:

```
queen = queen - 1
```

Or even better:

```
queen -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
the variables were being set and changed within the function which made python go crazy.
seting all the variables as GLOBAL first seemed to fix it

```
cards = 52

ace = 4
queen = 4
king = 4
jack = 4
two = 4
three = 4
four = 4
five = 4
six = 4
seven = 4
eight = 4
nine = 4
ten = 4
def ask_what_card_was_drawn():
    drawn_card = str(input("What card did you draw?: "))
    global cards

    global ace
    global queen
    global king
    global jack

    global two
    global three
    global four
    global five
    global six
    global seven
    global eight
    global nine
    global ten
    if drawn_card == "ace":
        ace -= 1
        cards -= 1
    elif drawn_card == "queen":
        queen -= 1
        cards -= 1
    elif drawn_card == "jack":
        jack -= 1
        cards -= 1
    elif drawn_card == "king":
        king -= 1
        cards -= 1
```